# Can SVGFigure be scaled as VectorFigure in Graphiti?

Tags: raphael, graphiti-js

I have been playing with the demos of Draw2D Graphiti, just curious to know if its possible to scale (change width/height in editor) SVGFigure for example the OpAmp, just like how basic shapes can be scaled ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of graphiti (0.9.87) has this feature built-in.